# Laravel not getting all request data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I want to pass `select2` multiple select values to database using ajax in my laravel project. Before using ajax, I passed the values using get requests. All values are shows as url parameters, but when it checks with a request -> `all()` it gets the token value and the last value only, other values are not shown. Why are some other values missing? How can I get all values? I also want to store them in a database. Additionally how can I send those values using ajax.

full URL example: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_services?_token=oo6hLRavd6mPczbsgjwQ8RXSNUohhktO5NyNGxCN&services_select=6&services_select=8&services_select=7

Here is my ajax request(send data using ajax instead of normal form submission):

```js
$('#submit-service').click( function() {
    var terms = $("#service-select").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/send_services',
        data: terms
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I want to send this data mainly using ajax.

Comment: brother ,what is the value of terms ,please check that first , did you get multiple value in terms variable ? do console or alert for debugging. after debugging you will understand everything :)

Comment: as I know if you send get/post request and few fields have same name it will only take last one and overwrite previous , u need to use unique names / u use multiple time : services_select name and i think this is an reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add array in name attribute of select tag 
  for e.g

```
<select multiple="" name="multiple_values[]" id="service-select">
```

Comment: thanks. it works! how can i store them to DB.  i am to laravel

Comment: if you want to store those multiple value  to one column, you need to concatenate those value with comma in controller .

Comment: @Hashan for only concatenation part ?

Comment: yes. i added a foreach loop, but i can not understand pass values to db. `            foreach ($services as $id=>$value) {
                DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value]);
            }` this is the code. but it gives the error"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `services` (`0`, `1`) values (6, 9))" . Is that any proper way to do this?

Comment: @Hasan you are doing wrong , just concatenate string before inserting to db

Comment: Can you please send the code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59285189/how-to-store-multiple-values-in-one-column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204052/discussion-between-neeraj-amoli-and-hashan).

Answer (score 0):

Sending values using `ajax` and `GET` is the same, you simply use the URL:

```js
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '/send_services?data1=value1&data2=value2&data3=value3'
});
```