# How to store multiple values in one column

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store multiple values which comes from `select2` multiple values in my laravel project. It returns an array with all inputs contains service ids. I want to store each value into database in the `service_id` column. How can I do this? I am new to laravel, using laravel 5.8.

`dd()` output of request:

[image]

here is my code:

```html
$services = array();
 $services = $request->except('_token');
 foreach ($services as $id=>$value) {
   DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value]);
 }
```

It gives this error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `services` (`0`, `1`) values (6, 9))"

how can I solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly have a think about if you really want to do this - or normalise your database and do it properly?!

Comment: Better to store all id in separate table, if you store all ids in one row it will be difficult for other operation, better to normalize it.

Comment: No i want to store each ids in each rows.

Comment: share your table structure @Hashan

Comment: because `insert into services (0, 1) values (6, 9))` in your table column name different not like `0,1` its `service_id`

Comment: here is the service table https://ibb.co/ZWP5GrG

Comment: @Hashan please write this sttement just below foreach print_r($value); and let me know , what it is printing

Comment: Here is the output :  Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 )  i want to store 5 and 4 in each row of service table.

Comment: you want to store ids in one filed by comma separated?

Comment: DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value]);  replace this to DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value[$id]]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing an array to service id.
In your case the key will be services_select and value is an array in your foreach loop.

Try this

```
$services = $request->except('_token');
foreach ($services['services_selects'] as $id => $value) {
  DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value]);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Great @Jaseelb thanks a lot! you save my time. it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
try this
 $services = $request->except('_token');
 foreach ($services['services_selects'] as $index => $value) {
   DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value]);
 }
```

Comment: @Hashan please check this answer and let me know it's working or not?

Comment: Thanks for the code. but it give "Undefined index: services_select"

Comment: Again it gives that error "Undefined index: services_selects"  :(

Comment: @Hashan brother i changed my solution , now check i write this
$services = $request->except('_token');
foreach ($services as $id=>$value) {
  DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $value[$id]]);   
}

Comment: brother, what is the change? it still gives that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204055/discussion-between-neeraj-amoli-and-hashan).

Answer (score 0):

That is not great approach but if you have to do it in one column just add the (,). 
First create local variable to store all your data then insert to the table

```
     $services = array();
     $services = $request->except('_token');
     $var = "";
     foreach ($services as $id=>$value) {
       $var = $var .",".$value;
     }
     DB::table('services')->insert(['service_id' => $var ]);
```